# Show untracked files only in specific folder

Tags: git, shell, zsh, git-status

My dotfiles are in a [barebone git repository](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles). To avoid showing all files in my home folder every time I run `git status`, I set `status.showUntrackedFiles = no`.

However, I'd like the `$HOME/.zsh/custom` folder to be exempt from this rule as it only contains code relevant to my dotfiles. How could I manage such exclusion?

I've tried using a `gitattribute` file but [per documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) it doesn't seem that we can change arbitrary configuration per file. I've also looked if there is a `gitconfig` file scope per folder, but it also seems like a dead end ([documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)).

Do you have any idea how to manage this? I'd be happy with a hack as long as running `git status` shows me untracked files only for a specific folder.

I'm currently using `git status -uall .zsh/custom` as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If you home folder is a git repo, then why not try and configure `~/.gitignore`  to ignore files and folders? That's actually exactly what I do for my home folder repo

Comment: That would be quite cumbersome for me as I add loads of things in this folder unfortunately. Still interesting though, might default to it!

Comment: Whoa! Everything mentioned in a .gitignore is considered expendable by Git and could be deleted at the blink of an eye. Don't ever list important stuff in .gitignore.

Comment: yes - if its important, i would track it in git, not ignore it.

Comment: @j6t Can you explain  more? In fact `.gitignore` can protect files from being removed by `git clean`, which will obligingly ignore the files matched by `.gitignore` and not clean them, unless you override that behavior with `-x`.  In which situation will Git delete `.gitignore` files at the blink of an eye, such that they would have been spared if not matched by `.gitignore` rules?

Comment: @Kaz Most importantly, when a name changes from being a file to being a directory or vice versa due to a checkout operation. This also includes merge operations. There may be other situations. The important point is that Git treats the names as unimportant. The general idea is that these are build products, hence, reproducable.

Comment: @j6t you make a very good point actually. Cannot remove my upvote but wont use for sure. It would also mess with every tools relying on gitignore to traverse directories quickly (e.g. `fd some_file ~/` wouldn't work anymore, same with `rg`).